# Parsing Bitcoin URL Address format

Tags: java, android

How to parse this bitcoin URL in Android Java?

```
"bitcoin:address?label=mylabel&amount=12"
```

Then return value of bitcoin address, amount, label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String bitcoinUrl = "bitcoin:address?label=mylabel&amount=12";
String address = bitcoinUrl.replaceAll("bitcoin:(.*)\\?.*", "$1");
String label = bitcoinUrl.replaceAll(".*label=(.*)&.*", "$1");
String amount = bitcoinUrl.replaceAll(".*amount=(.*)(&.*)?", "$1");

Log.d("bitcoin", address);
Log.d("bitcoin", label);
Log.d("bitcoin", amount);
```

Result

```
D/bitcoin﹕ address
D/bitcoin﹕ mylabel
D/bitcoin﹕ 12
```

Comment: how to get bitcoin address?

Comment: But if I need to parse not only bitcoin addresses? For example I need single handler for litecoin, bitcoin, bitcoin cash etc currencies. Do you know solution?